When rendering a map chart, how do I change the stroke width (strokeWidth property doesn't seem to work)?
I'm trying to set the strokeWidth prop, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Am I doing anything wrong here?
This is how I'm trying to render it:
  // load the world polygon series
  var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(
    am5map.MapPolygonSeries.new(root, {
      geoJSON: am5geodata_worldLow,
      exclude: ["AQ"], // don't include antartica
      fill: am5.color(0xbbbbbb),
      stroke: am5.color(0xffffff),
      strokeWidth: 5,
    })
  )


If you go to the docs at this link you can read this Polygon appearance can be configured via its template, accessible via series' mapPolygons.template
So you have to use stroke and strokeWidth in the template function in this case setAll
polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.setAll({
  stroke: am5.color(0xffffff), // Use the color you wish
  strokeWidth: 2, // here is the stroke width
  fillOpacity: 0.5 // this is the opacity of the fill you can skip this if you want
});

